# How to debug this kernel crash?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Here's the situation:

I'm hooking a syscall to do some custom IO stuff. That custom IO stuff is crashing everything, but I'm struggling to track down what exactly's going wrong.

So a kernel module hooks the syscall. My application calls it, the kernel module handles it and makes some IO calls. It's sometimes then, sometimes after returning to userspace, that everything dies. My ssh sessions die (`Write failed: Broken pipe`), and I have to wait a minute before I can reconnect as it seems to reboot.

Nothing relevant is in `/var/log/{dmesg,syslog,kern.log}`. In fact, despite removing the `-` before `/var/log/syslog` in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`, the stuff I'm logging with `printk` that appears on my ssh'd tail of the syslog (pre-crash), is no longer there after the crash.

I have an ubuntu packaged kernel (`3.12.0-5-generic`) and its debug symbols.

How do I debug this crash? I can find no trace of it in the logs I've looked in.

Comment: Who written the kernel module ?

Comment: @stdcall Myself and a coworker

Comment: can you share the code of this custom IO stuff ?

Comment: @stdcall It's large, and that probably won't help. I'd like to know where there might be details of the crash stored, the nature of the crash, and anything I can do to debug it. I'm trying `kdump` but I can't get past `Could not find a free area of memory of a0000 bytes...  locate_hole failed * failed to load kdump kernel`

Comment: I can't hep you further without seeing the source. It seems that you looked in all places where the logs can be.

Comment: Put your Linux kernel module code on e.g. [github](http://github.com/) to show it. We cannot help without looking inside the source code. Notice that kernel code is not supposed to use syscalls (like `write(2)` ....).